# Insertion sort c++

Tags: c++, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm trying to practice with algorithms and I'm trying to write a prorgam that uses the insertion sort algorithm to arrange numbers in an array in ascending order, the numbers in the array are recieved via user input.

Now when I type in a bunch of random numbers, it only returns them in the order I put them in, anyone spot my error? See code below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 20; //global constant

void fillArray(int a[], int size, int& numberUsed)
{
    int next = 0;
    int index = 0;

    cin >> next;

    while ((next >= 0) && (index < size)) //Á meðan tala er stærri en 0, og heildarfjöldi minni en 20
    {
        a[index] = next; //gildi sett inn í array
        index++;
        cin >> next;    //næsta tala lesin inn
    }
    numberUsed = index; //
}

void sort(int a[], int numberUsed)
{
    int j, temp;

    for (int i = i; i < numberUsed; i++)
    {
        temp = a[i];

        j = i -1;

        while (temp < a[j] && j >= 0)
        {
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            --j;
        }
        a[j+1] = temp;

    }
}

void displayArray(const int a[], int numberUsed)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < numberUsed; index++)
        cout << a[index] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "This program sorts numbers from lowest to highest.\n";
    cout << "Enter up to 20 nonnegative whole numbers.\n";
    cout << "Mark the end of the list with a negative number.\n";

    int sampleArray[MAX_SIZE], numberUsed;

    fillArray(sampleArray, MAX_SIZE, numberUsed);
    sort(sampleArray, numberUsed);

    cout << "In sorted order the numbers are:\n";
    displayArray(sampleArray, numberUsed);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `int i = i;` is necessarily what you wanted.

Comment: Are you sure? I've just tried your code and it works properly.

Comment: It really works for you? I tried creating a new project, copy and pasting the code in again and build+run. But it still only returns the numbers in the order I input them. I'm use Xcode btw

Comment: What should I be using instead of i @WhozCraig

Comment: `int i = i` is undefined behavior, so it can work properly if you are lucky, but it is not guaranteed to.

Comment: Oh wow I see it now, it should have been i = 1, thanks ! :)

Comment: @Birgir _" it should have been i = 1,"_ **Nope!** Thoroughly read what the answers are saying! Array indices start with `0`.

Comment: Ahh yes, I tried both and changed it to 0, thanks everyone for the answers!

Comment: While you're fixing other problems you need to fix the inner loop of `sort()`. You must test that `j` is valid __before__ using it as an array index. The inner loop should be `while (j >= 0 && temp < a[j])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
for (int i = i; i < numberUsed; i++)
```

It should be this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberUsed; i++)
```

Answer (score 3):

works fine, just replace

```
int i = i;
```

with:

```
int i = 0;
```